# Passing parameters in spacebars template yields 'First argument must be a function' error

Tags: meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm trying to follow lectures on the EventedMind.com website and in the "Shark UI Preview: Rendering with the Inclusion Tag" video I'm getting this error:

> > First argument must be a function, to be called on the rest of the arguments; found STRING

on the asterisk'd line below in my code.html file.  I presume I'm not including the right package.  Here are the packages I'm currently using

meteor list --using
standard-app-packages
autopublish
insecure
spacebars-compiler -- I get the same error with or without this

...and this is the version of Meteor I'm using
meteor --version
Release 0.8.2

================================
from code.html:

```
<head>
  <title>Rendering with the inclusion tag</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello Dan!</h1>
```

*      {{> greeting "Joe" "Smith"}}

```
<template name="__greeting">
  Greetings!
</template>
```

====================================
from code.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.helpers({
    greeting: function(firstName, lastName){
      console.log(firstName, lastName);
      return Template.__greeting;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have anything to do with packages.

Your complete error looks like this:

```
While building the application:
client/views/pages/test.html:4: First argument must be a function, to be called on the rest of the arguments; found STRING
...type="update"}}  --> {{> greeting "Joe...
                        ^
```

Look at the `^` in the error message.

It's saying that your first argument after `{{> greeting` needs to be a function. Instead it got a string, `"Joe"`. So you're not calling your spacebars helper correctly.

Try `{{> greeting firstName="Joe" lastName="Smith"}}`

Reference: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/spacebars-secrets-exploring-meteor-new-templating-engine/